# How do I create a custom event in Svelte?

Tags: svelte

I've been using `on:click` and looking for an event using Svelte. How do I trigger a custom event within a child component that I can capture in a parent component? I've seen a tutorial where I can pass in something like this, however, I couldn't get it to hook up.

```
<Component on:customClick={myThing}>
```

The child component has some logic that looks like this:

```
    <script>    
       export let myThing = '';
    <script>  

<input type="text" onClick={() => myThing= 'Update'} />
```

This does not seem to work, what am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could dispatch event from children component and handle it in parent component

```
// children component
<script>
    import { createEventDispatcher } from "svelte";

    const dispatch = createEventDispatcher();

    let count = 0;

    function handleClick() {
      count += 1;
      dispatch("customClick", {
        count
      });
    }
</script>

<button on:click={handleClick}>
  Clicked {count} {count === 1 ? 'time' : 'times'}
</button>
```

```
// parent component
<script>
  import ChildrenComponent from "./ChildrenComponent.svelte";

  let count;

  const handleCustomClick = event => {
    count = event.detail.count;
  };
</script>

<main>
    <p>Parent count: {count || 0}</p>
    <ChildrenComponent on:customClick={handleCustomClick}/>
</main>
```

Below is the codesandbox demo

[image: Edit restless-paper-n8ter]

**Reference:**

[Tutorials: Component events](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/component-events)

Answer (score 2):

Or like this (without dispatch):

Parent:

```
<script>
  import Child from "./Child.svelte";

  let count = 0;
  const handleClick = () => {
    count += 1;
  };
</script>

<main>
    <p>Parent count: {count}</p>
    <Child {count} on:click={handleClick} />
</main>
```

Child:

```
// child component
<script>
    export let count;
</script>

<button on:click>
  Clicked {count}
</button>
```